# Angular 2 npm start does not ignore node_modules

Tags: npm, angular

This is how my tsconfig.json file looks like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

This is about 5% of what my console prints every time i run npm start. The rest of the output is similar. It basically goes through every @angular module.

```
16.05.10 22:47:13 304 GET /node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/core_private.js
[1] 16.05.10 22:47:13 304 GET /node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/lifecycle/lifecycle_annotations_impl.js
[1] 16.05.10 22:47:13 304 GET /node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/lang.js
[1] 16.05.10 22:47:13 304 GET /node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/async.js
[1] 16.05.10 22:47:13 304 GET /node_modules/@angular/common/src/pipes/invalid_pipe_argument_exception.js
[1] 16.05.10 22:47:13 304 GET /node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/intl.js
[1] 16.05.10 22:47:13 304 GET /node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/collection.js
[1] 16.05.10 22:47:13 304 GET /node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/exceptions.js
[1] 16.05.10 22:47:13 304 GET /node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.js
[1] 16.05.10 22:47:13 304 GET /node_modules/@angular/common/src/forms/directives/shared.js
[1] 16.05.10 22:47:13 304 GET /node_modules/@angular/common/src/forms/directives/number_value_accessor.js
[1] 16.05.10 22:47:13 304 GET /node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/facade/lang.js
[1] 16.05.10 22:47:13 304 GET /node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/template_parser.js
[1] 16.05.10 22:47:13 304 GET /node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/config.js
[1] 16.05.10 22:47:13 304 GET /node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/compile_metadata.js
[1] 16.05.10 22:47:13 304 GET /node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/offline_compiler.js
[1] 16.05.10 22:47:13 304 GET /node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.js
[1] 16.05.10 22:47:13 304 GET /node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/url_resolver.js
[1] 16.05.10 22:47:13 304 GET /node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/view_resolver.js
[1] 16.05.10 22:47:13 304 GET /node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/directive_resolver.js
[1] 16.05.10 22:47:13 304 GET /node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/pipe_resolver.js
[1] 16.05.10 22:47:13 304 GET /node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/html_parser.js
[1] 16.05.10 22:47:13 304 GET /node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/directive_normalizer.js
[1] 16.05.10 22:47:13 304 GET /node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.js
```

Even though I have chosen to exclude node_modules they are scanned through every time I run npm start (which takes about 30 seconds..). This happened after I updated to to beta rc.1. Does anyone have a solution how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct and intended behavior. Your web server just shows the files that it is serving since they have been requested by the browser.

In `tsconfig.json` you are telling TypeScript compiler to ignore node_modules from compilation.